# Variable referenced before assignment error even after using global variables python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using this code in a function inside pyqt5 class.

```
        print(len(k))
        print(len(u))

        if len(k) / 3 < len(u):
            c = len(k) / 3 + 1
            c = round(c, 0)
        elif len(k) / 3 < len(u):
            c = len(u) + 1

        print(c)
```

here k and u are lists

My IDE(PyCharm) is giving a warning "Variable referenced before assignment" on hovering over variable "c" line "print(c)"

The output is printed as 
8
2
and after that python stopped working

Where 8 and 2 are the lengths of the lists

I have tried using functions and global variables as

```
        print(len(k))
        print(len(u))

        def getvar(a,b):
            global c
            if a / 3 < b:
                c = a / 3 + 1
                c = round(c, 0)
            elif a / 3 < b:
                c = b + 1
            return c


        print(getvar(len(k),len(u)))
```

This is printing
8
2

and again python stopped working

Can someone suggest how i can work my way around this.

PS all this code is inside a fuction in a pyqt5 class

e.g.

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
       ...some..code..
       self.startBtn.clicked.connect(self.run)

    def run(self):
       ...some..code..

       ** code mentioned above**
```

I am using python3.6

Comment: Why are the conditions in `if` and `elif` the same?

Comment: typo in the condition, warning is still there (variable might be referenced before assignment),

Comment: What about `len(k) / 3 == len(u)`?

Comment: adding an else statement cleared everything :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this:

```
    if len(k) / 3 < len(u):
        c = ...
    elif len(k) / 3 < len(u):
        c = ...
```

First, the conditions (`len(k) / 3 < len(u)`) are the same and the `elif` won't ever be executed. The `unused variable`-conditions arises because neither of the arms may get executed; then `c` is undefined. Go with an `else` block that catches that, e.g. by raising `ValueError`.

Comment: Thaks for pointing out, it was a typo(caussed by maybe a lot of hit and trial methods) and it did removed the python not responding error and using an else statement rremoved the warning too

Answer (score 3):

```
    if len(k) / 3 < len(u):
        c = len(k) / 3 + 1
        c = round(c, 0)
    elif len(k) / 3 < len(u):
        c = len(u) + 1

    print(c)
```

first, both conditions are the same! (that shouldn't bother your IDE which probably cannot analyze that far), but more importantly you're missing a `else:` so potentially `c` *could* be undefined.

Comment: missin else statement was causing the warning :)

Comment: yeah that's expected. But also fix your identical conditions (seen twice in your code) Oh you edited it. We'll revert it, you should not edit & fix your code when other people answered. It makes the answers moot.